# Running Python in Visual Studio 2017, output not showing correctly?

Tags: python, debugging, ide

I was using a different IDE for running Python scripts, but I would like to switch over to Visual Studio. When I try testing simple scripts that work in the simple IDE, I can't figure out how to get my output to show correctly. I have tried running the debugger, pressing CTRL+F5, and pressing CTRL+F5 then CTRL+d, but all that happens is that a blank console pups up, and the cursor blinks actively.

I have run out of ways to rephrase this issue to get something helpful to show up in both Google search results and in StackOverflow. The main results I get are about antivirus software (thoroughly investigated, not the problem here) and articles about beginning Python in VS. How do I get my Python programs to show output correctly? And also am I using incorrect terminology?

[What happens when I hit Ctrl+F5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCug0.png)

Answer (score 1):

Have you already gone through the Installation,  Quickstarts and Tutorials here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/overview-of-python-tools-for-visual-studio

Make sure the simple hello_world.py file with one line works:

```
print("Hello World")
```

If you still have problems,  it may be that Visual Studio does not realize you have Python installed (i.e. if python is not in your path variables).